# Override React Component base styles with props

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, theming

I have the following function that overrides my components base styles with custom values passed through as props:

```
function overrideCardContainerStyles (props) {
  const {
    width,
    height,
    borderRadius,
    backgroundColor,
    paddingVertical,
    paddingHorizontal,
  } = styles.cardContainer;

  const {
    cardWidth,
    cardHeight,
    cardBorderRadius,
    cardBackgroundColor,
    cardPaddingVertical,
    cardPaddingHorizontal,
  } = props;

  return { 
    width: cardWidth || width,
    height: cardHeight || height,
    borderRadius: cardBorderRadius || borderRadius,
    backgroundColor: cardBackgroundColor || backgroundColor,
    paddingVertical: cardPaddingVertical || paddingVertical,
    paddingHorizontal: cardPaddingHorizontal || paddingHorizontal,
  };
};
```

While this strategy works and is suitable for overriding a few styles it wont be effective as the project grows. I'm envisioning that almost every defined base style within the project will have the option to be overridden with a prop.

Is there a better way to achieve this in a more elegant and scalable manor?

Comment: Why don't you use the `styles` prop and merge that into the styles variable?

Comment: I appreciate the answer as this pointed me in the right direction. I used the spread spread operator and merged the two objects. Final piece of the puzzle was this article: https://davidwalsh.name/merge-objects

Answer (score 1):

You could use [loadash merge](https://lodash.com/docs/#merge) for that. Just merge the passed props into your style props, so that if it is undefined, the fallback will be used. Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate your answer as it pointed me in the right direction. I used the spread operator to merge my base styles with my overrides. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend naming your styles with the same naming system and passing their properties within a single property.

For example:

```
function overrideCardContainerStyles (props) {
  const {
    width,
    height,
    borderRadius,
    backgroundColor,
    paddingVertical,
    paddingHorizontal,
    ...props.styles,
  } = styles.cardContainer;

  return { 
    width,
    height,
    borderRadius,
    backgroundColor,
    paddingVertical,
    paddingHorizontal,
  };
};
```

I do it this way:

```
const Box = ({ styles }) => (
  <div style={{ color: 'red', ...styles }}>
    Color Text
  </div>
);

const Card = () => (
  <Box styles={{ color: 'green' }} />
);
```

Comment: Great answer but I went with a different strategy:

`function mergeStyles (base, overrides) {
  return {
    ...base,
    ...overrides,
  };
};`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Styled System library, which you can use with Styled Components or Emotion:

Create a component this way:

```js
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { color } from 'styled-system'

const Box = styled.div`
  ${color}
`

export default Box
```

The `color` function adds color props `color` and `bg` to your component:

```js
<Box color="black" bg="blue">
  Blue Box
</Box>
```

Likewise, the `space` function will give you to margin and padding props:

```js
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { space } from 'styled-system'

const Box = styled.div`
  ${space}
`

export default Box
```

```js
<Box ml={3} p={3}>
  Box with spacing
</Box>
```

`ml` stands for marginLeft and `p` for padding.

There are several other functions such as `layout` for stuff like width and height, 'border'...

It also comes with great features like theming and responsive props.

(Examples taken from https://styled-system.com/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

I had a different solution - please note that this will only work for material-ui components (as far as I know).

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  card: {
    backgroundColor: "inherit",
    borderRadius: "0px",
    boxShadow: "none"
  }
}));

export const MyCard = props => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card style={props.style} className={classes.card}>
      <CardContent>
        {props.label}
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

And in my main component, I'd called it in this manner:

```
<MyCard
    style={{ width: "125%", color: "red" }}
    label={"This is my card"}
/>
```

Material-UI will give precedence to the style prop over its className prop, so you can pass in custom styles.